# getting 'Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method' in Spring security while trying to secure APIs jwt

Tags: java, spring-boot

here is the code , where I changed

```
.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
```

with this

```
.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
```

because first one was deprecated

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain security(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.
                csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
```

**but i am getting an error**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-28T21:04:52.508+09:00 ERROR 29616 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'security' defined in class path resource [com/example/webbackend/Config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'security' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/resource/web/BearerTokenResolver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:818) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:133) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
```

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace** instead of a snippet.